# Python send email when sensor has certain water level

Tags: python, logic

I am developing an application on a raspberry pi with an HC-SR01 sensor. For now I have a python script that checks the water level every second.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO_TRIGGER = 16
GPIO_ECHO = 18

GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO, GPIO.IN)

def distance():
    # set Trigger High
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, True)

    # set Trigger after 0.1ms low
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)

    startTime = time.time()
    endTime = time.time()

    # store start time
    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO) == 0:
        startTime = time.time()

    # store arrival
    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO) == 1:
        endTime = time.time()

    # elapsed time
    TimeElapsed = endTime - startTime
    # multiply with speed of sound (34300 cm/s)
    # and division by two
    distance = (TimeElapsed * 34300) / 2

    return distance


while True:
    dist = distance()
    print ("Entfernung = %.1f cm" % dist)
    time.sleep(1)
```

This is working fine and now I want to send an E-Mail to myself then the water level is above a certain limit. The sending of the E-Mail is not the problem but the logic when to send it.
If I put a sendEmail() function in the while loop I would get an E-Mail every second when the water level is reached. So the following wouldn't do it:

```
#global varaible
alarm_waterlevel = 170

#in while loop
if dist > alarm_waterlevel
  sendMail()
```

So I'm looking for a clever solution to only send the mail once the water level is reached.

I was thinking about a global variable and check if the water level has dropped below a certain point before triggering the mail again. Something like this:

```
#global varaible
alarm_waterlevel = 170
mail_sent = false

#in while loop
if dist >= alarm_waterlevel && mail_sent == false
  sendMail()
  mail_sent = true
if dist <= alarm_waterlevel - 10
  mail_sent = false
```

Do you think this is a fault tolerant solution? Any good advices out there to help me get around with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach looks reasonable to me, for a Raspberry Pi solution ;)

Another thing that you could think of is adding maybe three different warning levels or states that your system can be in.

```
L1: send once, 80% full
L2: send every 5 minutes, 90 % full
L3: send every minute, > 100 %
```

And you have to think of when to change the states. You could add something like a hysteresis. That could be elegant so you don't have to use three different height levels.

If the water level increases you could switch the state, e.g. at 80 % but only switch back to a lower warning state when it is below 70 %. The idea is that your system is not constantly changing states when the water level is between 78 % and 82 %.

Another thing that you could think of is like a projection by looking at the derivative (first or maybe additionally second) of the water level. Then you could warn even earlier when the water level is rising quickly but it is still below a critical threshold.

Comment: This is awesome, I'll defenitly give this a try. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a general logic problem in your if statement.
You want to send an e-mail when the distance is greater than or equal to your alert level.
I think your ultrasonic sensor measures from top to bottom, so your if statement should be:

```
size_water_container = 200 #Just a estimadet value
if dist < (size_water_container - alarm_waterlevel) and waterlevel_before > (size_water_container - alarm_waterlevel):
    sendMail()
```

If i am wrong, than ignore it :)
But now to your Question.
If you permanently query the distance, than you have to permanently save your waterlevel_before, but not in the if statement. Just do it afterwards

```
alarm_waterlevel = 170
size_water_container = 200
waterlevel_before = 0
while True:
    dist = distance()
    if dist < (size_water_container - alarm_waterlevel) and waterlevel_before > (size_water_container - alarm_waterlevel):
        sendMail()
    waterlevel_before = dist
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I think that does not solve the question, it will still send all the time

Comment: @Don CorliJoni you're right I have to invert the logic. Because in my test environment I have tested it the other way which is wrong. Thanks for this hint.